# Need a word to summarize this: Inaction in a moral crisis because you can’t make a difference anyway

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, someone doesn’t practice environmentally friendly choices because they think there’s no point since no one else is doing it and so they might as well enjoy it. It’s not like it will have any major impact on the environment given their actions alone.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample sentence which would use the word.

Comment: You feel your efforts would be *futile*, so why make the effort.   Not sure what you mean when you say "so they might as well enjoy it".  Enjoy what?

Comment: The right forum may be economics. The problem is that for the individual, there is no benefit in doing the right thing. If others do the right thing, I get the benefits. This is called a free-rider problem, which occurs with public goods—goods I can enjoy without contributing effort or resources.  Public goods are those that are not diminished by any one person’s use and it’s hard to exclude anyone from their use.

Comment: National defense is a public good. The solution is to tax to fund it.

Comment: Clean air is a public good, but more difficult. To deal with it laws are created with penalties and encouragements provided to increase individual behavior that helps maintain clean air (or in general. a good environment). People are incentivized to separate recyclables, trash, and compostables, for example, with various penalties if they don’t. Obviously it gets mote complex—gasoline autos vs. electric, etc.

Comment: Thus none of the dupes do anything but condemn the slacker, which doesn’t help much.

Answer (score 0):

That word is 'acquiescence'. A sense of resignation or inaction in the face of a moral crisis because of perceived inability to make a meaningful difference.